# Passing Two Strings Between Activities but both Received are the same

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Until now I have been sending 1 string to my next activity and it has been working fine, but when I tried to add a second string to add I always miss one of my passed strings. Am I missing something obvious? When I switch the last extra sent, that is the value that both received strings display as.

Example:

Both values in activity 2 equal only 1 of the values sent from activity 1 (the last sent value from activity 1).
Activity 1 sends: 
string1_send = "str1"
string2_send = "str2"

Activity 2 receives:
string1_rcv, expecting "str1", but receiving "str2".
string2_rcv, expecting "str2", and receiving "str2"

Activity1:

```
public void newGame (View view1)
    {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, gameScreen.class);
        if(musicEnable == true){

            intent1.putExtra(musicEnablePass, "music_ON");
            intent1.putExtra(aviMF_choice, aviSelected);
        }
        else{
            intent1.putExtra(musicEnablePass, "music_OFF");
            intent1.putExtra(aviMF_choice, aviSelected);
        }
        startActivity(intent1);
    } //aviSelected is a string "male"
```

Activity2 (In my onCreate):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            aviChoice = extras.getString(aviMF_choice);
            Log.i("test", ""+musicEnabled_Pass +" , "+aviChoice); // returns "null, null"
            musicEnabled_Pass = extras.getString(musicEnablePass);
            Log.i("test", ""+musicEnabled_Pass +" , "+aviChoice); // returns [aviMF_choice value],[aviMF_choice value]

        }
```

Comment: check value of aviChoice when you are passing it in intent whether it is null or has some value

Comment: what u send in aviSelected???

Comment: Getting both values in `Log.i("test", ""+musicEnabled_Pass +" , "+aviChoice); ` log then what is your Question?

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini it is a string

Comment: **1-** make sure `musicEnablePass` and `aviMF_choice` (as keys) are not the same value, **2-** make sure `musicEnablePass` in activity 1 +2 and `aviMF_choice` in activity 1 +2 are same values . to be sure you are setting and getting with the same KEY

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK both values in activity 2 equal only 1 of the values sent from activity 1 (the last sent value from activity 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your keys from variables to simple strings. Currently your "Activity2" is only receiving one string and assigning it twice because your keys aren't being "recognized" as two different unique keys as you haven't assigned them as such. The reason it works at all is because you are effectively sending data so in Activity 2 it indeed sees that "extras != null" but it only provides the default value (probably the only key it knows of: the last sent). Unless you already assigned unique strings to each respective key already
Example your "musicEnablePass" may just be a null variable,

```
String musicEnablePass; // this returns a null value/string
```

vs

```
String musicEnablePass = "musicEnablePass";
```

So change (your code):

Activity1.java

```
intent1.putExtra(musicEnablePass, "music_ON");
intent1.putExtra(aviMF_choice, aviSelected);
```

Activity 2.java

```
aviChoice = extras.getString(aviMF_choice);
            Log.i("test", ""+musicEnabled_Pass +" , "+aviChoice); // returns "null, null"
musicEnabled_Pass = extras.getString(musicEnablePass);
```

To this (corrected code):
Activity1.java

```
intent1.putExtra("musicEnablePass", "music_ON");
intent1.putExtra("aviMF_choice", aviSelected);
```

Activity 2.java

```
aviChoice = extras.getString("aviMF_choice");
            Log.i("test", ""+musicEnabled_Pass +" , "+aviChoice); // returns "null, null"
musicEnabled_Pass = extras.getString("musicEnablePass");
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you for the description and the explanation!!! This works!!!